# Excel VBA Print function inserting new line / CR

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print to a file using the following statement

```
Print #1, "String1"; Tab(20); "String2"; Tab(15); "String3"
```

such that the file reads

```
String1                    String2               String3
```

and then begins a new line. But what actually results from execution of the above statement is:

```
String1                    String2
               String3
```

For reasons I can't seem to figure out, a new line is inserted after String2, but not after String1.

If anyone knows how to fix this, please do tell. Thank you!

Comment: I am using this example, which seems to work for them and not me. [link](http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson12.html) As I understand it, the semicolon suppresses the insertion of the new line and carriage return.

Comment: what happens if you replace the semi-colon for a &?

Comment: @SamWard I tried that, and it wouldn't compile. D: Looks like it has to be delineated with semicolons or commas.

Comment: How are you viewing the file? are you doing it in notepad and is wordwrap on?

Comment: @Sorceri Unfortunately, it's not that. I tried Notepad and Notepad++ and ensured word wrap was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tab(20);` doesn't insert 20 tabs - it sets the position to the "20th" tab (where ever that is).  You can't then set it back to 15 on the same line...

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I thought it just inserted that many spaces.

I changed it to `Print #1, "String1"; Tab(20); "String2"; Tab(35); "String3"` and it works as desired.

Thank you!